# Numpad always controls the mouse pointer

Tags: gnome, keyboard, numpad

My numpad always controls the mouse pointer no matter how many times I toggle the numlock. I checked on `xev` and numlock is triggering but no change in behavior.

I also tried with `numlockx on|off` but that didn't help either.

Have gone through all keyboard settings under Ubuntu and Gnome Tweak Tools. Nothing related to numpad as mouse pointer.

I use BigBagTrix for colemak layout and have gone through all its settings too and nothing related to numpad.
Even tried setting `numpad:microsoft` with `XKBoption` inside that program but no change.

What am I missing? It doesn't seem to be an hardware issue(could there be such an option within BIOS??) but I am not sure what setting needs to be changed.

Comment: Sounds like [you might have "Mouse Keys" enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html.en) 

Comment: @matigo that was it. didn't even recall this was an option. +1

Comment: @matigo The mousekey gets enabled after every reboot. Any possible reason as to why that may be? I don't see any way I am accidentally triggering it with a shortcut.

Comment: It's not something I've run into, but you may be able to disable it from the Terminal like this: `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/keyboard/mousekeys-enable false`. Hopefully this persists across reboots. If not, you may need to create a new question to ask how to run that command every time you log in 

Comment: @matigo thanks. I will put it in bashrc if it gets enabled on reboot.